# Remove file that contains specific string in href via JS

Tags: javascript, html

In `HubSpot` a file called `layout.min.css` is automatically added and is you cannot disable this `css` file anywhere in the CMS.

As such, I've tried to `remove()` and `disable` the file via JS, but the styles from that css file are still being rendered.

When I `view source`, this file looks like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/xxxxxx/hub_generated/template_assets/1642616240355/hubspot/hubspot_default/shared/responsive/layout.min.css">`

Now, notice the `1642616240355` in the URL? That number (for some reason) changes everyday.

Yesterday, I had the following running, and it removed the file:

```js
$("link[href='//cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/xxxxxx/hub_generated/template_assets/1642528871696/hubspot/hubspot_default/shared/responsive/layout.min.css']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("link[href='//cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/xxxxxx/hub_generated/template_assets/1642528871696/hubspot/hubspot_default/shared/responsive/layout.min.css']").remove();
```

However, as it keeps changing, I'm now looking to remove and disable any css file that contains `layout.min.css` in its `href`.

I'm aware that there's a `:contains` selector, which might be of use here, but unsure on how that would be implemented? As in, how would I tell the code to look at all stylesheets and remove the one that `contains` "layout.min.css" in its `href`?

Have also tried:

```html
<script>
  const stylesheets = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet]');
  for (var i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
    if(stylesheets[i].href.indexOf("responsive/layout.min.css") >= 0) {
      stylesheets[i].disabled = true;
      stylesheets[i].remove();
    }
  }
</script>
```

But it still shows the `layout.min.css` when viewing source.

Comment: CSS has a `*=` selector, does `$('link[rel=layout.min.css]').remove()` work?

Comment: the sample code you shared works? demo: https://jsitor.com/kI7v5VOH8E

Comment: Can you add a snippet where the problem can be reproduced here? It would be quite difficult to test a solution, because in order to do so, we would need to construct the exact problem you have. If you could do that instead in your question, then please ping me here in the comment section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to do this with pure JavaScript instead of JQuery. Because otherwise you have to wait until the JQuery library is loaded.

Use this code for that:

```js
const cssElement = document.querySelector("link[href*='layout.min.css']");

cssElement.disabled = true;
cssElement.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided that you said works, why not use the ends-with matcher: `$=`?

```
$("link[href$='layout.min.css']").remove();
```

That'll find all the `<link>` HREFs that end with 'layout.min.css' and remove them, which is exactly what you're describing as your goal.